# JS Math.random() duplicates previous value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a skate dice for web browser, but almost every time i get the same results, even when the page has been refreshed for the function to run again.

```
<script>
function closeit()
{
document.getElementById("popup").style.display ="none";
}

function reload()
{
window.location.reload(),
setTimeout(10000);
}
var rolldie1 = Math.random();

if (rolldie1 <= 0.50)
  {
    answer1 = "";
    document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="";
  } else if (rolldie1 <= 0.60)
  {
    answer1 = "Switch";
    document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Switch";
  } else if (rolldie1 <= 0.65)
    {
      answer1 ="Nollie";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Nollie";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.75)
    {
      answer1 ="Fakie";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Fakie";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.90)
    {
      answer1 ="Frontside";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Frontside";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.99)
    {
      answer1 ="Backside";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Backside";
    }
  else if (rolldie1 <= 0.50)
    {
      answer1 ="";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="";
    }
function show1()
{
  var elem = document.getElementById("popup");
    elem.style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("popup");
}

function sa1()
{
sa2();
sa3();
sa4();
document.getElementById("a1").textContent = answer1;
}
</script>
<script>
function reload()
{
window.location.reload(),
setTimeout(10000);
}

var rolldie2 = Math.random(), answer2; 

if (rolldie2 <= 0.30)
  {
    answer2 = "Kickflip";
    document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Kickflip";
  } else if (rolldie2 <= 0.40)
    {
      answer2 ="Heelflip";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Heelflip";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.60)
    {
      answer2 ="";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="";
    }
 else if (rolldie2 <= 0.90)
    {
      answer2 ="Pop Shove";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Pop Shove";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.94)
    {
      answer2 ="360 Flip";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="360 Flip";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.99)
    {
      answer2 ="Varial";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Varial";
    }
function show1()
{
  var elem = document.getElementById("popup");
    elem.style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("popup");
}

function sa2()
{
document.getElementById("a2").textContent = answer2;
}
</script>
<script>
function reload()
{
window.location.reload(),
setTimeout(10000);
}

var rolldie3 = Math.random(), answer3; 

if (rolldie3 <= 0.16)
  {
    answer3 = "";
    document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="";
  } else if (rolldie1 <= 0.60)
        {
          answer3 ="360";
          document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="360";
         }
     else if (rolldie3 <= 0.95)
         {
          answer3 ="540";
          document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="540";
        }
 else if (rolldie3 <= 0.97)
    {
      answer3 ="720";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="720";
    }
 else if (rolldie3 <= 0.99)
    {
      answer3 ="900";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="900";
    }
 else if (rolldie3 <= 0.90)
    {
      answer3 ="180";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="180";
    }
function show1()
{
  var elem = document.getElementById("popup");
    elem.style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("popup");
}

function sa3()
{
document.getElementById("a3").textContent = answer3;
}
</script>
<script>
function reload()
{
window.location.reload(),
setTimeout(10000);
}

var rolldie4 = Math.random(), answer4; 

if (rolldie4 <= 0.90)
  {
    answer4 = "Nose Manual";
    document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Nose Manual";
  } else if (rolldie4 <= 0.60)
    {
      answer4 ="";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="";
    }
 else if (rolldie4 <= 0.80)
    {
      answer4 ="Manual";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Manual";
    }
 else if (rolldie4 <= 0.85)
    {
      answer4 ="Nollie Pivot";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Nollie Pivot";
    }
 else if (rolldie4 <= 0.95)
    {
      answer4 ="Sexchange";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Sexchange";
    }
 else if (rolldie4 <= 0.99)
    {
      answer4 ="Cross Foot";
      document.getElementbyId("popup").textContent ="Cross Foot";
    }
function show4()
{
  var elem = document.getElementById("popup");
    elem.style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("popup");
}

function sa4()
{
document.getElementById("a4").textContent = answer4;
}
</script>
```

This is what i have tried. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: use this to get 1-6 numbers Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, I would also try to avoid all this "if" and use map array will make it very simple

Comment: see jsfiddle I think this way will be better start http://fiddle.jshell.net/z7gurhs6/

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/z7gurhs6/1/